# Descomprimir archivo .zip(imag1,imag2,imag3) en Java

Tags: java, oracle, spring

Me encuentro en como poder descomprimir un zip que contiene imagenes, lo que deseo hacer es descomprimir el archivo y guardar las imagenes de tipo [] a mi BD.

Help me, please.

Comment: revisa esto: http://www.baeldung.com/java-compress-and-uncompress

Comment: Pudiste resolverlo?